# New to Minecraft, keep spawning in a dark cave, how do I get out?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I haven't ever played Minecraft before, but my daughter wants to play (because of course her friends have it).  I setup a Minecraft server using nukkit on a Raspberry Pi 3, and then downloaded the Minecraft iOS app.

I initially launched with the default world but then kept spawning -- and drowning -- in water.  I downloaded the "Summer Secrets" map to the server and join that, now I don't drown but...

I keep spawning in what appears to be a very dark cave.   I tried `/suicide` but it ended up right back in the same spot.   I ran around hand-chopping at the walls but can't seem to find a way out of this and it is extremely hard to see.

Comment: While Nukkit is written in Java, it's a server for Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

That's very unlucky.
An easy solution could be to generate another world and hope to spawn in a better place.

Otherwise, you could use Minecraft commands.

You can change the location where a player respawns after dying to any coordinates in the game with the [/spawnpoint](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/spawnpoint_command.php) command.

In Minecraft Java Edition, the syntax to reset the spawn point for a player to a new location is:

```
/spawnpoint [targets] [pos]
```

> ##### Definitions
>
> - **targets** is optional. It is the name of a player (or a target selector) whose spawn point you wish to change. If you don't specify a player, the spawn point for the player running the command will be changed.
> - **pos** is optional. It is the x y z coordinate to use for the spawnpoint. If you don't specify a coordinate, the command will use your current position in the game.

---

There should be also a generic `/setworldspawn`

```
/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>
```

Use `/setworldspawn` by itself to set the spawn point for all players to the point you’re currently at. Use `/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>` with x y z coordinates to set a new spawn point for all players.

Comment: When you say "generate a new world", what is the command to do that?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code I mean from the main menu, create another world with a different seed. But that doesn't work on a server.